# Звук при входящем сообщении на сайте

Tags: javascript, аудио, web-audio, уведомления

Здравствуйте.

Нужно, чтобы при входящем сообщении на сайте проигрывался звук, по типу, как у контакта! Как это реализовать? Скрипт проверки на наличие сообщений имеется, как в него вставить воспроизведение звукового файла?

Решил проблему так:

```
function soundClick() {
 var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
 audio.src = 'n.mp3'; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
 audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
}
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что этот код не кроссбраузерный. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) Советую использовать какой-нибудь простенький плагин, например https://github.com/evandrolg/audiojs. Сам не пользовался ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю не создавать объект Audio каждый раз, ведь вы можете создать его однажды и использовать повторно

Ниже накиданный на скорую руку симулятор чата

```js
function MessageClass(userName, text, avatarSrc, sendTime){
    var self = this;
    
    this.UserName = userName;
    this.Text = text;
    this.SendTime = sendTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    this.AvatarSrc = avatarSrc;
}

var chat = new function (){
    var audio = document.createElement('audio'),
        source = document.createElement('source'),
        tid = 0;

        source.type = 'audio/mpeg';
        source.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a';
    
    audio.appendChild(source);
    
    this.Messages = ko.observableArray([]);
    
    this.Messages.subscribe(function (){
        clearInterval(tid);
        
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
        
        // только потому что трек длинный
        tid = setTimeout(function(){
            audio.pause();
        }, 400);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(chat, document.getElementById("chat"));

(function onMessage(){
    chat.Messages.push(
        new MessageClass(
            faker.name.firstName() + ' ' + faker.name.lastName(), 
            faker.hacker.phrase(), 
            faker.image.avatar(),
            new Date()
        )
    );

    scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);

    setTimeout(onMessage, faker.random.number(1500) + 500);
})(chat, faker);
```

```css
fieldset{
    position: relative;
}

fieldset:nth-child(2n){
    margin-left:24px;
}

legend{
    color:#0a0;
}

time{
    position:absolute;
    right:12px;
    top:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    color: #a00;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

img{
    float:left;
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    border-radius:30px;
    height:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/examples/browser/js/faker.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id='chat'>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Messages">
        <fieldset>
            <legend data-bind="text: UserName"></legend>
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: AvatarSrc }" />
            <time data-bind="text: SendTime"></time>
            <div data-bind="text: Text"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вот здесь вы и сами можете писать сообщения:

```js
    function MessageClass(userName, text, avatarSrc, sendTime){
        var self = this;
        
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.Text = text;
        this.SendTime = sendTime.toLocaleTimeString();
        this.AvatarSrc = avatarSrc;
    }

    var chat = new function (){
        var self = this,
            tid = 0,
            audio = document.createElement('audio'),
            source = document.createElement('source'),
            generateFakeMessage = function (){
                self.Messages.push(
                    new MessageClass(
                        faker.name.firstName() + ' ' + faker.name.lastName(), 
                        faker.hacker.phrase(), 
                        faker.image.avatar(),
                        new Date()
                    )
                );
            
                scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);
            };

            source.type = 'audio/mpeg';
            source.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a';
        
        audio.appendChild(source);
        
        self.Messages = ko.observableArray([]);
        
        self.UserMessage = ko.observable('');
        
        self.sendMessage = function(){
            if (self.UserMessage()){
                chat.Messages.push(new MessageClass(
                    'My account', 
                    self.UserMessage(), 
                    '//s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/psdesignuk/128.jpg',
                    new Date()
                ));
                
                self.UserMessage('');
            }
                
            setTimeout(generateFakeMessage, 1000);
            
            return false;
        };
        
        self.Messages.subscribe(function (){
            clearInterval(tid);
            
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 1;
            audio.play();
            
            // только потому что трек длинный
            tid = setTimeout(function(){
                audio.pause();
            }, 400);
        });
        
        generateFakeMessage();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(chat, document.getElementById("chat"));
```

```css
    fieldset{
        position: relative;
    }

    fieldset:nth-child(2n){
        margin-left:24px;
    }

    legend{
        color:#0a0;
    }

    time{
        position:absolute;
        right:12px;
        top:0px;
        background:#FFF;
        color: #a00;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0px 6px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    img{
        float:left;
        width: 60px;
        margin-right: 12px;
        border-radius:30px;
        height:60px;
    }

    input, button{
        margin-top:6px;
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/examples/browser/js/faker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

    <div id='chat'>
        <div data-bind="foreach: Messages">
            <fieldset>
                <legend data-bind="text: UserName"></legend>
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: AvatarSrc }" />
                <time data-bind="text: SendTime"></time>
                <div data-bind="text: Text"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form data-bind="submit: sendMessage">
                <input autofocus='autofocus' type="text" placeholder='Type your text here' data-bind="value: UserMessage" /> 
                <button>send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Кстати, код для пробы http://jsfiddle.net/SanSYS/jc16eumk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не грузить аудиофайл каждый раз при воспроизведении, можно воспользоваться замыканием:

```js
var soundClick = (function () {
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = 'http://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-TG100-Ocarina-C5.wav';

  return function () {
    audio.play();
  };
})();
```

```html
  <a href="" onclick="soundClick(); return false">Звук!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Плагин [**Ion.Sound**](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/index.html)

Вот [несколько примеров](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo.html) использования.

```
// Настройка плагина
ion.sound({
    sounds: [
        {
            name: "message_sound"
        }
    ],
    volume: 0.9,
    path: "sounds/",
    preload: true
});

// Проигрываем звук!
ion.sound.play("message_sound");
```